# Install libssl0.9.8 package

Tags: libssl

I need to install libssl0.9.8 package on my 64 bit centos 6.3 machine.I tried doing this by using this command:
sudo yum install libssl0.9.8. I am getting the following error:
No package libssl0.9.8 available. Error: Nothing to do
How do I proceed with this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,
yum install openssl-0.9.8

As far as i know thats the package containing libssl.so.0.9.8.

Comment: Well, I am able to get libssl now. Thanks